Only spelling suggestions from user-defined list
Unfortunately I have not managed to run pspell with a custom list only.
I have tried different configurations, but the result remains the same. Either I load the complete Dictionary including my words or no words at all. The advice from ChatGPT has not helped either.
I also checked the following link, but the files are in a different location and unfortunately I'm not very familiar with command lines (most of them are blocked by my provider).
Pspell use only custom dictionary
Since I now suspect that there is no quick solution with Aspell (or Pspell), I wanted to ask about alternatives in PHP?
How can I get spelling suggestions in PHP based only on my customised list?
I am happy for any feedback.

Simply for completion. Here is a solution that meets my requirements.  Maybe it will help someone else.
            // Open dictionary (a serelized PHP array)
            $File                = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/gratia_wortliste.ser');
            $GratiaWordlistArray = unserialize($File);

            $Words = str_word_count($enquery, 1, 'äöüßÄÖÜß');

            $enqueryNew = '';
            foreach ($Words as $Word)
            {
                // Check Word
                if (in_array($Word, $GratiaWordlistArray))
                {
                    $enqueryNew .= $Word . ' ';
                }
                // Wrong word; make a suggestion
                else
                {
                    $suggestionArray = [];

                    foreach ($GratiaWortlistArray as $Suggestions)
                    {
                        $Distanz = levenshtein($Word, $Suggestions);
                        // Levenshtein-Abstand ≤ 5 
                        if ($Distanz <= 5)
                        {
                            $suggestionArray[$Suggestions] = $Distanz;  
                        }
                    }

                    // sort by Levenshtein-Distanz
                    asort($suggestionArray);
                    $Suggestion = array_key_first($suggestionArray);

                    if ($Suggestion)
                    {
                        $SuggestionsTipp = true;
                        $enqueryNew .= '<i><b>' . $Suggestion . '</b></i> ';
                    }
                    else
                    // No Suggesion
                    {
                        $enqueryNew .= '<i>' . $Word . '</i>';
                    }
                }
            }


Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. - see What topics can I ask about here? and [ask].
